# OpenCV: Normalizing pixel values of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to normalize the pixel values of an image to have a mean value of 0.0 and a norm of 1.0 to give the image a consistent intensity. There is one OpenCV function, i.e. `cvNormalize(src,dst,0,1,cv_MINMAX)`, but can this function be used for my purpose? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you are using an old version of opencv. please read the latest [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/).

Answer (score 16):

**No, the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mean#normalize) for `normalize` says**:

When `normType=NORM_MINMAX` (for dense arrays only), the functions `normalize` scale and shift the input array elements so that:

[image: equations]
<sub>(source: [opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/_images/math/31bceb122fccfc14279355379f91c7b269290386.png))</sub>

Hence, if you use `normalize(src, dst, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32F);`, your data will be normalized so that the *minimum* is 0 and the *maximum* is 1.

**It is not clear what you mean** by giving the pixel values of the image mean 0.0 and *a norm of 1.0*. As you wrote it, I understand that you want to normalize the pixel values so that the norm of the vector obtained by stacking image columns is 1.0. If that is what you want, you can use `meanStdDev` ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mean#meanstddev)) and do the following (assuming your image is grayscale):

```
cv::Scalar avg,sdv;
cv::meanStdDev(image, avg, sdv);
sdv.val[0] = sqrt(image.cols*image.rows*sdv.val[0]*sdv.val[0]);
cv::Mat image_32f;
image.convertTo(image_32f,CV_32F,1/sdv.val[0],-avg.val[0]/sdv.val[0]);
```

If you just want to normalize so that the variance of the pixel values is one, ignore the third line.

And yes, the `CV_32F` means that the resulting image will use 32 bit floating point datatype (i.e. `float`).

Comment: Actually I am working on a object tracking project,there I need to convert the images to have mean 0.0 and norm of 1.0, to give the images consistent intensity , i.e. to reduce the effect of different illumination condition.

Comment: @Anislein343 it's still not clear what is supposed to have "a norm of 1.0"... Anyway, if you want to effectively reduce the effects of different illumination conditions, a global normalization of the image won't help you. Have a look at these articles instead: [link1](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=6690823132241966720), [link2](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=14271520333736502311), [link3](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=2687681104163852721), [link4](http://scholar.google.fr/scholar?cluster=14602528712956028312).